# HttpServletRequest in simple java application

Tags: java, wsdl, httprequest

I creadet a simple Java app via Maven for wsdl web service. it's not a web application, and my question is: can i use HttpServletRequest/Response in such off apps or I must create dynamic web app?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need HttpServletRequest/HttpServletResponse in your simple stand alone java app ? HttpServletRequest/HttpServletResponse are interfaces provided by Oracle inside the Servlet Specification. It is the task of WebServer vender to provide the implementation of these interfaces. So the webserver can populate a native HTTP request into the HTTPServletRequest and can provide to the Servlet. If your application not hosted on a webserver, you could not get the HttpServletRequest object.

Answer (score 0):

Once I have used **`HttpServletRequest/HttpServletResponse`** in my simple java app for Mocking.

At that time, i add **`servlet-api-2.5.jar`** to my project and then i will be able to mock it.

But you cant make it a web-app like this.For that you have to create dynamic web-app.